# Error while creating Kafka topic through command line

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka_2.8.0-0.8.1.1 version.

I am trying to create kafka topic using the following command:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.25.3.131:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

But i get the following error:

`Error while executing topic command replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:70)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:155)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:86)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:50)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)`

Any suggestions regarding how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started your Kafka broker?
Try this:

`./bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties`

Comment: yes i have started kafka broker and zookeeper,but still i get the error.

Comment: Then you must be having problem with communication between ZK and Kafka broker. Can you run this command: `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.25.3.131:2181 --describe --topic test`

Comment: Yes i can run this command but with no output, there is issue while creating topic.

Comment: Issue while creating topic? Which one? What's the error message, if any?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. when I ren bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.131.168:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic clicks_topic1 but did not get any output.